# onRestart() clarifications

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

### From the Android documentation:

*When the same instance of the covered activity comes back to the foreground, the system calls onRestart(), onStart(), and onResume() on the activity. If it is a new instance of the covered activity that comes to the background, the system does not call onRestart(), only calling onStart() and onResume().*

First of all, how come it is a new instance available there in the background. Also, if it is a new instance how come onCreate() is skipped..? Basically someone please elaborate second line in the above documentation paragraph with an example that how it is that onRestart() will be skipped being called.